# jQuery object moves in timeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a timeline bar like below

```
<div class="plan-bar main-gradient"></div>
```

[image: timeline bar]

Now how do I make the ***red box*** moving ***base on realtime***?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: What do you mean by "realtime"?

Comment: base on system datetime sir

Comment: what have you tried? can you post your code?

Comment: something like this:- http://jsfiddle.net/XqqtN/  just change left to right. Also you have to clear yourself that how's you want it to move based on datetime and how much you want to move.Also you shown no codding effort

Comment: it is not diffcult to make it move, but i want the red box to move itself everyday a little bit

Answer (score 0):

I've got this work fine right [here](https://jsfiddle.net/latiosthinh/k0d7Lbvz/10/). Thank you everyone.

```
function update() {
 var wB = 600;
 var wA = 0;
 var hours = new Date().getHours();

 var d = 20;
 var total_d = 20
 pos_rad = ((d)*24 + hours) / ((total_d)*24.00);

 xCoord = (wA) + wB*pos_rad;
 $(".Box").css({
    "left": xCoord
 });
 setTimeout(function(){ update(); }, 1000);
}

$(function(){
  var today=new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth()+1;
  if ( dd==14 && mm==6) {
   update();
  }
});
```